# cURL and DOM document

Tags: curl, domdocument

I need help whit cURL and DOMdocument.
How can i get the value of the hidden input element? Because the value is variable i cant select the value whit cURL!?
This is the form:

```
<form action=​"test.php" method=​"post">​
<input type=​"submit" value=​"Doorgaan">​
<input type=​"hidden" name=​"q" value=​"07ojc71sie1ysxikw4kvn5i3eb5nw6exd3gpahisvjqoh99ddt9">​
</form>​
```

Can someone help me whit it?

Thanks in advance!
Regards,

Jordy Van Camp

Answer (score 0):

Use cURL with [xmllint](/questions/tagged/xmllint)'s xpath. This will only show the HTML elements "input" with a "hidden" attribute

```
shell~> curl http://example.org/ | xmllint --html --xpath "//input[@type='hidden']" -
```

To pull the value of the items returned by [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath), use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), or [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)

```
shell~> curl http://example.org/ | \
        xmllint --html --xpath "//input[@type='hidden']" - | \
        sed 's/.*value="\(.*\)".*/\1/'
```